# Execlp doesn't mutate correctly

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to mutate a program and it keeps giving me error(-1).

```
execlp("history","history", NULL)
```

I don't know where history is found.

Comment: Define what you mean by *mutate*

Answer (score 1):

On some shells, including [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), `history` is a [builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html#index-history), like `cd` is (and `cd` invokes [chdir(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html); there is no *useful* <strike>`/bin/cd`</strike> executable, and there cannot be any). So there is no such executable.

You should consider instead using the [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) library in your program. See first [readline(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) then [history(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/history.3.html).

If you confusingly do have some `history` [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) in [your `$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (a strange setup), use [execvp(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

Alternatively, code your [shell *function*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) (e.g. defined in your `~/.bashrc`) using that `history` builtin.

Comment: On both Mac OS and Linux, there is an executable `/usr/bin/cd`.   It is required by POSIX.  It isn't very useful, but it does exist.