# Using GDB in linux if running application from a script

Tags: c++, gdb

Normally we run gdb with gdb command and our application name. But if we want to run our application from a script eg my_script.sh as ./my_script.sh argument and this starts our application. Then how to use gdb without including any command in script.

I want something like this : gdb ./my_script.sh argument. So that whatever application will be started from script I can debug it.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62128190/edit) your question to motivate or explain with more details your use case. Perhaps you could be interested by [Ian Taylor's libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace)

Comment: Please motivate your question. Why do you want to run `gdb`   programmatically? Are you coding some IDE?

Comment: No I don't want. I want something like this : gdb ./my_script.sh argument. So that whatever application will be started from application I can debug it.

Comment: "I want something like this : gdb ./my_script.sh" but **why?** **You are confused: do you want to debug a shell script or an ELF executable?** Without a lot more explanations, **your question stays unclear.**

Comment: The executable/application which will be started.

Comment: Please don't comment your own question. Take five more minutes to add complete sentences in written English to it.

Comment: **Your question is now completely unclear**. I don't understand what program you want to debug, and in which programming language it is written (C++ is not `bash`). If you want to debug a `bash` script, why did you tag your question as `C++` ?

Comment: You can run `gdb sh --args sh ./my_script.sh argument`, but  gdb will not know which of possibly many programs spawned by the shell script you want to debug.

Answer (score -1):

> Normally we run gdb with `gdb command` and our application name.

This is **wrong**. You use `gdb` on some binary [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file (in ELF format) or (with `-p`) on a running [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). For example, you cannot run <strike>`gdb cd`</strike> but `cd` is a shell [builtin command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/bash-builtins.7.html) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042579/841108)). BTW an executable file can have *several* names (e.g. `/bin/rbash` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` on my Debian computer), and programs can be started without being "applications" on your desktop menu. For example, my `g++` executable would run `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus`. Check with [strace(1)](http:///usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1) or by diving into the [source code of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html), or simply [adding](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-v` inside your `g++` command.

### Read [documentation of GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

and the [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) and [gdbserver(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdbserver.1.html) man page. 
Run also in a terminal `gdb --help` to understand how you could start it.

You might start (or improve your `my_script.sh` shell script to run) your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable `yourprog` (obtained by compiling your C++ code) using

```
 gdb --args yourprog arg1toit arg2toit
```

and you could even use some [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (see [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) or even [unix(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets) to pour commands into it. Of course `yourprog` should be compiled [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -g` and perhaps also `-O` (assuming a recent enough [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)).

In addition, recent GDB can be scripted or [extended](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html#Extending-GDB) in [Python](https://python.org/) or in [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). You might need to compile and configure GDB from [its source code](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/), which you are allowed to do since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

**If you need to debug a `bash` shell script, consider using [`bashdb`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/), a shell script debugger**. Of course spend an hour in reading its documentation. But if you want to debug a script coded in `bash`, *why is your question tagged C++ ?*

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

However, a process won't be able to debug directly itself without precautions. See [ptrace(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) for details.

> I want something like this : `gdb ./my_script.sh` argument.

#### This is not possible.

GDB can (on recent Linux distributions) only debug an ELF [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (but not a shell script), preferably with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information. Design your `my_script.sh`  to sometimes run `gdb`. That debugged executable would be often compiled with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compilers (and `-g` options) from some C++ or C source code. You could find other compilers ([Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), [Rust](http://rust-lang.org/), [Go](https://go-lang.org/), ...) capable (with care) to produce ELF executables with DWARF debug information.

If your `my_script.sh`  is written for GNU bash (so starts with `#!/bin/bash`, see [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) for details), read the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). **You might consider rewriting your script** in [Python](https://python.org/) or in [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or in [Lua](https://lua.org/), since all these scripting languages are more expressive than POSIX shells. In all cases, **read the documentation of the scripting language you have chosen to use**. Most of them have debugging facilities. (you could replace `#!/bin/bash` with a line like `#!/bin/bash -vx` as the first line of your shell script).

NB. Notice that  `/usr/bin/firefox` is often a script starting some `/usr/bin/firefox.real` ELF executable. You could glance inside it for inspiration.